# Django CreateView doesn't save instances to the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created a model and a CreateView for it, the model does not have a ForeignKey to a user, so anyone can create an instance of it without creating an account, but when I fill the form, I get redirected to the success URL and nothing gets saved in the database, below is my code.

models.py:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    set1 = models.EmailField(max_length=400)
    set2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"set1 is {self.set1} and set2 is {self.set2}"
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Data

class Data_entry(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
            model = Data
            fields = ["set1", "set2"]
            widgets = {
                "set1":forms.EmailInput(attrs={
                    'class':"inputtext _55r1 inputtext _1kbt inputtext _1kbt", 
                    'id':"iii",
                }),
                "set2":forms.TextInput(attrs={
                    'id':"ooo",
                    'class':"inputtext _55r1 inputtext _1kbt inputtext _1kbt",
                })
            }
```

views.py:

```
class Gmyp(CreateView):
    model=Data
    form_class = Data_entry
    success_url=reverse_lazy("Bye")
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(Gmyp, self).form_valid(form)
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Did you run `manage.py migrate` after creating the model?

Comment: Yeah, I did the model is craeted and saved when i create it from the admin site or the db @Exelian

Comment: I think there's a typo. The `Gymp` view should use `model=Data` not `models=Data`

Comment: @Exelian Thanks for noticing this, this sure is a big problem but even after correcting it, the instnace does not get saved

Answer (score 0):

in views.py, change form_valid to :

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    return super().form_valid(form)
```